# Notifications for events that don't exist

Tags: windows-10-mobile, calendars, notifications, lock-screen, lumia-640

I used to have an event that took place daily in my Outlook Calendar, but as of last week, the event is cancelled. Outlook Calendar itself says "No events today".
However, the notifications on the lock screen keep arriving every day. How can I turn those off?

Note: I do not want to turn off the notifications altogether. I need those notifications! Only for this event, that isn't there any more.